# ¿Cómo puedo deserializar un JSON con parámetros agrupados en C#?

Tags: c#, jsonobject

Entiendo que la respuesta valdría para xml u otros.

Recibo un JSON que tiene grupos de parámetros.

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Juan",
  "email": "CJuan@dana.io",
  "address": {
    "street": "Dayna Park",
    "number": "Suite 449",
    "city": "Bartholomebury",
  },
  "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
  "company": {
    "name": "NTTDATA",
    "job": "TEAM LEADER"
  }
},
```

¿Cómo debemos definir la clase que recibirá la deserialización de este JSON?

Traté de crear clases dentro de clases y deserializar contra la principal, pero solo la primera recupera los valores, los otros recuperan null.

```
 class Users
   {
       public int id { get; set; }        
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string email { get; set; }
       public Adress adress = new Adress();
       public string phone { get; set; }
       public Company company = new Company();
   }
   class Adress
   {
       public string street { get; set; }
       public string number{ get; set; }
       public string city { get; set; }
   } 
class Company
   { 
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string job{ get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/ y https://app.quicktype.io/ Te aconsejo borrar la pregunta para que evites votos negativos, ya que no se permiten preguntas que pidan recomendaciones de herramientas.

Comment: Buenas, podrías publicar el código de como recuperas actualmente el json para que podamos reproducir y si es el caso indicar si usas alguna libreria externa. Ya que aún sin herramienta creo que se puede hacer algo

Comment: Tienes 2 errores: 1) es `address` con 2 `d` y el principal es que TODO tiene que ser `property` incluso los que son de tipo "Address" y "Company", es decir te falta los `{ get;set}` en es esas 2, ejemplo `public Company company {get;set;} = new Company();`

Comment: Estaría bien que menciones la librería y cargues el código que estás usando. La pregunta está cerrada, pero cuando esté en condiciones puedes solicitar su reapertura.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he resuelto con lo indicado por [yussef](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/301324/yussef)

```
Tienes 2 errores: 1) es address con 2 d y el principal es que 
todo tiene que ser property incluso los que son de tipo "Address" 
y Company", es decir te falta los get;set en es esas 2, ejemplo 
public Company company {get;set;} = new Company();
```

[rexxarcat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/293967/rexxarcat) adjunto el código completo y definitivo.

Ejemplo completo del JSON:

```
{
  "id": 9,
 "name": "Glenna Reichert",
 "username": "Delphine",
 "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
 "address": {
   "street": "Dayna Park",
   "suite": "Suite 449",
   "city": "Bartholomebury",
   "zipcode": "76495-3109",
   "geo": {
     "lat": "24.6463",
     "lng": "-168.8889"
   }
 },
 "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
 "website": "conrad.com",
 "company": {
   "name": "Yost and Sons",
   "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
   "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
 }
},
```

Las clases para deserializar.

```
 class Users
 {
     public int id { get; set; }        
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string username { get; set; }        
     public string email { get; set; }
     public Address address { get; set; } = new Address();
     public string phone { get; set; }
     public string website { get; set; }
     public Company company { get; set; } = new Company();
 }
 class Address
 {
     public string street { get; set; }
     public string suite { get; set; } 
     public string city { get; set; }
     public string zipcode { get; set; }
     public Geo geo { get; set; } = new Geo();
 }
 class Geo
 {
     public string lat { get; set; }
     public string lng { get; set; }
 }
 class Company
 { 
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string catchPhrase { get; set; }
     public string bs { get; set; }
 }
```

El código de llamada al WebServices y la deserialización. Usando las clases HttpClient para la llamada y JsonSerializer para deserializar.

```
class WebServices
 {
    private static List<Users> users = new List<Users>();

   public static async Task<List<Users>> GetUsers()
    {
        string urlWS = "https://*****************/users";
        try
        {
            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            {
                var res = await client.GetAsync(urlWS);
                if (res != null)
                {
                    var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Users>>(content);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
        return users;
    }

}
```

Comment: Vale gracias por publicar el codigo para los que busquen en el futuro

Comment: No olvides mencionar qué decía el comentario de _Yussef_, ya que los comentarios son efímeros (si desaparece el comentario, se perderá el contexto de la respuesta).